# Can _Generic be a function? Or can _Generic be used with __attribute__((cleanup))?

Tags: c, generics, c11

Given the following source-code:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>

static inline void closedirp(DIR **p) {
    if (*p)
        closedir(*p);
}

#define auto_cleanup(resource) _Generic((resource),     \
    DIR **: closedirp,                  \
        )(resource)

int main() {
#ifdef GENERIC
    __attribute__((cleanup(auto_cleanup))) DIR * t2 = NULL;
    t2 = opendir("/tmp");
#else
    __attribute__((cleanup(closedirp))) DIR * t1 = NULL;
    t1 = opendir("/tmp");
#endif
}
```

It compiles and runs without leaks, with no defines. However when one defines GENERIC, the compilation fails:

```
$ gcc foo.c -DGENERIC
foo.c: In function ‘main’:
foo.c:16:2: error: cleanup argument not a function
  __attribute__((cleanup(auto_cleanup))) DIR * t2 = NULL;
  ^
```

This is pretty pointless use of _Generic, however I wanted to extend it and handle many types of resources to automatically clean up.

Answer (score 1):

`_Generic` is not a function but a keyword that starts a primary expression.

But here, you seem to be even more on the wrong track: `auto_cleanup` is a macro. Function like macros have the particularity that they are not expanded if there are no `()` comming after it. So here you just keep the the identifier `auto_cleanup` for later phases of the compilation. But this identifier isn't declared to be anything for these later phases.

To summarize:

- your macro, if used correctly, would be replaced textually in a very early phase of compilation
- then later phases would see a `_Generic` expression and decide which branch of that `_Generic` expression is taken
- only that branch would "survive" and be compiled in that part of the code

In all of this there is no function or function pointer involved that could be used for gcc's `cleanup` extension.